# Strange situation about drawing on a UIView and dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c

`if(point.y < UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 120 )`

should the following if statement satisfy this condition:

if the y is less than screenheight - 120
the Y being a point on the UIView that was tapped

Here is a log that shows some data output

```
Point [x]: 367.666656 
Point [y]: 623.333328  
Height [height]: 436.000000
```

In this output, I am tapping below what is supposed to be 623 and I still have the If condition not satisfied ??

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.sheet.isDrawn = NO;

    }

    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    NSLog(@"Test");



    if(self.sheet.zoneSet == YES)
    {
        if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            [self.sheet moveToPoint: location]; // declare the point variable in the header file.
            self.sheet.isDrawn = YES;
        } 


              NSString *xy = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" Point [x]: %1f Point [y]: %2f  Height [height]: %3f" ,  location.x , location.y,  UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 120];

        NSLog(xy);



        if( location.y  < (UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height - 120) )
        {

        [self.sheet addPoint: location];
       }

        }//Do stuff here...
}
```

Updated to display code where the Log occurs.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you log the output?

Comment: Yes of course. I just updated my original post.

Comment: `location` is relative to `recognizer.view.superview`. If that view is bigger than the screen, it is possible (scrollView, etc.).

Comment: How do I find the according .y ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring when you assign the variable **location** it's value.

You're using the superview. As described in the comments, the superview's bounds may be outside the bounds of the screen. Instead, you need the location to be derived from the UIView placed on the top of the viewController's hierarchy.

Try using `self.view` or, if you have added a subview that is pinned to the edges of the screen, use that `UIView`.

[Here's](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/you-probably-dont-understand-frames-and-bounds/) a link about **bounds & frames** that should help and it's by a programmer that I would recommend using as a resource. It maybe a little outdated, but his tutorial breakdowns of the basic Objective C foundations are worth a glance.